# What is the opposite of a POJO?

Tags: java, pojo

Anyone know what the opposite of a Plain Old Java Object is?

I'm talking about your typical terrible java class. Very complicated, tightly coupled, non-modular quagmire of ridiculousness?

Is there a term for a such a class?

Comment: If I would write the term down for such a class, my comment would be marked as offensive.

Comment: WTF object. would be a good candidate

Comment: How about NOJO ? Nightmarish Old Java Object or Notably Offensive Java Object.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you understand what is meant by POJO, from wiki-pedia a POJO object is simple an object that doesn't:
Extend a prespecified class, implement a prespecified interface or use annotations.

Basically this means an object that isn't part of a broader framework. Most badly designed, tightly coupled java objects are still POJO.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing such the "opposite" of the POJO.

[POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) is a simple java object (as you correctly say) and is used to separate them from objects which server special causes. I mention some example object categories which are not POJOs:

- [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)
- [java bean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)
- [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)
- [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) objects
- [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) objects

Hope I helped!

Comment: EJBs and JavaBeans are generally POJOs as well, read your own link that explains the POJO concept on wikipedia ;)

Comment: @Arjan While the POJO is a well formulated concept for experienced programmers, there is no "formal" definition of it. I suppose my answer gives the user a useful point of view. All these types of objects (EJB, DTO, CORBA etc) are **old**, and **plain java objects**. Following the strict definition, all java objects are POJOs. Whether a specific type is a POJO or not, is mainly a matter of opinion and not knowledge. However, if you disagree with my answer, you could downvote it...

Comment: No need to downvote ;) As with many things true definitions for everyday terms can indeed be ambiguous or non-existent (try e.g. looking up the one and only definition for "application server"). That said, in my understanding a POJO is a class without a required (framework) interface and without a required inheritance from a (framework) base class. The experts don't agree whether a required annotation counts or not. An EJB 3 bean without an annotation is thus surely a POJO. We can argue wether one with an annotation is or is not a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

The term POJO is a bit overused. You need to define it clearly so that you can come up with an opposite in your line of thinking. Following could give you an idea.

"POJO describes Java objects or classes that can function on any java context." 
Following this description you can probably consider it to be the opposite of Enterprise Java Beans in a Java EE context.

Have a look at Enterprise Java Beans for more information.

Comment: >`you can probably consider it to be the opposite of Enterprise Java Beans in a Java EE context.` - Only EJB 2 beans are that opposite. EJB 3 beans are POJOs. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object

Answer (score 0):

I know "Big Ball of Mud" is a term applied to software architectures that have the characteristics you describe, so maybe you could apply this term to classes as well.