# What is POJO defined as in tapestry

Tags: java, annotations, tapestry, pojo

I am new at tapestry, and from my understanding POJO does not extend, implements or use annotation which are explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350353/what-is-the-opposite-of-a-pojo)

However, when I visited tapestry [webpage](http://tapestry.apache.org/)

I can't help but notice them saying this

> Simple POJO classes, streamlined templates, live class reloading, state-of-the-art exception reporting, first-class Ajax support, and a big library of built-in components: Tapestry is designed from the ground up to give you great productivity.

but when I done the tutorial the java classes actually does use Annotations like `@Validate("required")

 public String firstName;`
so what are they trying to claim by stating they use simple POJO classes? Please keep it simple so I can understand ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page and component classes in a Tapestry app are not required to extend a framework class, implement a framework interface, or use framework annotations. In that sense they are POJOs. However, you are free to do any of those yourself, and Tapestry does provide annotations that are a convenient way to add certain commonly needed functionality, such as the validation in your example.